# Force two separate tables to have same amount of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two separate tables in Excel that I would like to both have the same first column and the same amount of rows.

I filled in the first column of the second table by referencing the first column of the first table. I just need to know how to force the two tables to always have the same amount of rows as well as the same rows.

[image]

So lets say if I delete a row from Table 1 it should delete the same row from Table 2.

Same goes if I add a row to Table 1 it should add a row to Table 2.

The other columns in the tables will not contain the same data.

I have very little experience with tables but a decent knowledge of VBA so I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: The only way you'll be able to do this is with VBA.  Selecting both sheets at the same time doesn't work because Excel won't let you perform an operation such as Insert or Delete on two tables at once.

Comment: Twisty has a point. Excel is a spreadsheet, not a database. You would have to write a VBA program to do work on a sheet to perform tasks that otherwise is not a function of Excel. VBA is where Macros can be performed which is part of Excel, but you have to be versed in programming skills in order to accomplish more advanced algorithms.

Comment: Also I advice: Learn databases. MS Access is a database software, with real Tables. With a Table, you can perform Queries. Your question is about Querying Tables -- that's what databases are for. Excel isn't a database, but people keep trying to think it is.

Comment: I've provided a solution that will work with Excel. I still stand by my advice in learning databases and database management though. By creating a query on Data Tab, Excel will then create a duplicate table that "mirrors" the original "Table". A Table in Excel isn't really a table, it's still a Sheet. In a database a Table is only and always just a table and likewise a Query is a reference to a Table. Tables are maintained, whereas Queries yield sorted data in reference to the Table.

Comment: @ejbytes I'll take a look at your solution you just posted I haven't had access to a pc to test it out but I am in agreement with learning MS Access and databases in general what I want to do is better suited for one.

Comment: @MatthewLozoya I think this should resolve your problem for Excel. You can try a sample data set. It takes only a few seconds to complete. The solution is actually only the first line in bold-faced letters. If that doesn't register, then follow the images for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So lets say if I delete a row from Table 1 it should delete the same
>   row from Table 2.
>
> Same goes if I add a row to Table 1 it should add a row to Table 2.
>
> The other columns in the tables will not contain the same data.

---

**YES. Create Table. Select Data tab, From Table, yields a new Query Table that pulls its data from the source Table.**

---

*Procedure*

---

1a. Create A Table

1b. Name the SHEET, something useful (eg DB)
 

2a. Select Data Tab. 

2b. Select "From Table" in the "Get & Transform" section.

2c. Name this Query something useful (eg Table_DB) -- see img_3

2d. Close & Load the Query. -- see img_4


3. This is your new Table, a new Query on your original Table in Step_1. This Table is a working duplicate of your existing table. -- named Sheet5 image_5


4a. Rename your new SHEET, Sheet5, to something usefule like DB_QUERY. See image 6.

4b. Perform a Query on DB_QUERY table. Select the Age drop_arrow to perform Query.

4c. Select "Greater Than" in query selection. Let's try to only look at persons with Age greater than 30 years. -- see image_6

4d. This is the query. Enter 30. Press Enter to accept query. -- see image_7


5. Note in Step 4, there are only two persons with ages over 30 years of age. But Stan quit his job. Let's delete Stan from this DB (database). DO NOT DELETE FROM QUERY. Maintain the query's integrity by maintaining its source; the DB Table from step_1.

5b. Select the DB, by clicking on the correct Sheet Tab. -- see image_8

5c. Delete Stan from the Table. -- see image_9

5c-1. Likewise, if you add a person the person will also be added to the Query Table.

5d. Stan is now deleted from the DB Table. -- see image_10


6a. Stan is now deleted from DB Table. But, it seems that the DB_Query isn't revealing these changes? -- see image_11

6b. Actually the tables, DB and DB_Query, are both in sync. You just need to refresh the DB_Query; refresh query by clicking refresh icon -- see image_12


*If query isn't visually available as in step 6, Select the "Data" Tab, then select "Show Queries" in the "Get & Transform" section.*

---

REFERENCE IMAGES BELOW

---

image 1

[image]

image 2

[image]

image 3

[image]

image 4

[image]

image 5

[image]

image 6

[image]

image 7

[image]

image 8

[image]

image 9

[image]

image 10

[image]

image 11

[image]

image 12

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put the tables on different sheets, with the same column and row position.

When adding or deleting an entry, select all the sheets needing the operation (Ctrl + click individual sheets, or in case of many sheets, Shift + click first target sheet and last target sheet) and type normally or delete.

The operations will be performed on all selected sheets. Tested for Microsoft Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a decent answer without seeing the tables but by the sound of it, I think the simplest solution would be to use three tables. Make a new table that is `table 1` augmented by columns `2` - `n` of `table 2`. This is going to the only place you enter or delete data. Let say this is on a sheet called `raw data`

Then create a new table that will look identical to your original `table 1` on a new sheet. In the cells of this sheet have a formula something like

```
=IF('raw data'!A1<>"",A1,"")
```

Do the same for `table 2`, i.e. create a new sheet using that formula, but offset the columns appropriately.

I think using VBA for this will just complicate your spreadsheet unnecessarily and will involve 'hidden' functionality which could lead to difficulty debugging or handing over in the future.